# how to parse the given hash into desired output in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-hash

I had to send daily course update notification to the user. Update notification contain four types of `[:due,:missed,:over_due,:new]`. To make it easy I omitted unnecessary field from data like due and missed coz it the same as overdue and new format. Below-provided data belonged a user.   A user can be part of many courses that is why 2 different course_id there in the hash (course_id 20 and 30). The id represents here assignment_id in a particular course. 
The actual format of data are.

```
  { 
   1 => { #the 1st user
     :new => {
          1 => {
           :id => 1,
           :course_id =>20,
           :course_name => "B"
          },
          2 => {
           :id => 2,
           :course_id =>30,
           :course_name => "A"
         },
         3 => {
           :id => 3,
           :course_id =>20,
           :course_name => "B"
         }
       }
       :over_due => {}, #This is also having the same format as new
       :missed => {}, #This is also having the same format as new
       :due => {} #This is also having the same format as new
     },
    2 => { #this is 2nd user
       :new => {},
       :over_due => {},
       :missed => {},
       :due => {}
     }
   }
```

Suppose, This is just a dummy data I had created for a user for more clarity and explanation.

```
assignments = {
  :new => {
    1 => {
      :id => 1,
      :course_id => 20,
      :name => "A"
    },
    2 => {
      :id => 2,
      :course_id => 20,
      :name=>"A"
    },
    3 => {
      :id => 3,
      :course_id => 30,
      :name=>"B"
    }
  },
  :over_due => {
    4 => {
      :id => 4,
      :course_id => 20,
      :name => "A"
    },
    5 => {
      :id => 5,
      :course_id => 30,
      :name => "B"
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement to parse data into this format:

```
{
  20 => {
    :new => {
      1 => {
        :id => 1,
        :course_id => 20,
        :name=>"A"
      },
      2 => {
        :id => 2,
        :course_id => 20,
        :name => "B"
      }
    },
    :over_due => {
      4 => {
        :id => 4,
        :course_id => 20,
        :name => "E"
      }
    }
  },
  30 => {
    :new => {
      3 => {
        :id => 3,
        :course_id => 30,
        :name => "C"
      }
    },
    :over_due => {
      5 => {
        :id => 5,
        :course_id => 30,
        :name=>"F"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First, show us what you attempted so far. Then, what's the expected result in clear *words*. Some of your hashes have `:course_id` been transformed to `value` some other haven't... Give us some insight.

Comment: I had updated the question. look at the following code.
       hash = {}
      assignments.each do |type,type_data|
        type_data.each do |assignment_id,data|
          course_id = data[:course_id]
          hash[course_id] = {}
          hash[course_id][type]= {}
          hash[course_id][type][assignment_id] = data
        end
      end

Comment: @MukeshKumarGupta Don't write code in the comments section, it's very difficult to read. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44520178/edit) and format it nicely.

Comment: Also, could you provide a bit more context in terms of what problem you're *actually* trying to solve here? You've got a really ugly mess of hashes-of-hashes-of-hashes; there's probably a much better way to solve the actual problem.

Comment: This is the first time I am posting a question.  I keep in mind your suggestion.

Comment: I had to send daily course update notification to the user (valid user this is already taken care correctly). update notification contain four types of [:due,:missed,:over_due,:new]. To make it easy I omitted unnecessary field from data.  A user can be part of many courses that is why 2 different course_id there in the hash. The id represents here assignment id in a particular course. 1,2,3,4,5 are assignment id and 20,30 course_id.

Answer (score 1):

check below code for your solution:

```
 hash = {} 
 assignments.each do |type,type_data| 
    type_data.each do |assignment_id,data| 
        course_id = data[:course_id]
        hash[course_id] = {} if hash[course_id].nil?
        hash[course_id][type]= {} if hash[course_id][type].nil?
        hash[course_id][type][assignment_id] = data 
    end 
end
```

output:

```
{20=>{:new=>{1=>{:id=>1, :course_id=>20, :name=>"A"}, 2=>{:id=>2, :course_id=>20, :name=>"B"}}, :over_due=>{4=>{:id=>4, :course_id=>20, :name=>"E"}}}, 30=>{:new=>{3=>{:id=>3, :course_id=>30, :name=>"C"}}, :over_due=>{5=>{:id=>5, :course_id=>30, :name=>"F"}}}}
```

Comment: yeah! It is working. I got what I was missing. I was creating empty hash each time blindly. I think we can optimize. If I find any better way to do it. I will post in the same threads.  Thank you.

Comment: @MukeshKumarGupta Great. Accept my answer if it works for you> Thanks